# How to print file content only if the first line matches a certain pattern?

Tags: text-processing, files, regular-expression

I am writing a script, I want to check if the first line of the file matches a certain pattern and if it does then print out the file. How can I achieve this?

How do I check for pattern? Is there a way to check for pattern and based on the output do something..

EDIT:
Please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536018/how-to-get-match-regex-pattern-using-awk-from-file

I want something like this, but none of them worked for me. I basically want to check if the first line matches a regex pattern or not and based on that print the lines of file.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting? What is the pattern you're looking for? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @tachomi edited please take a look

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do that with `ed`:

```
ed -s infile <<\IN 2>/dev/null
1s/PATTERN/&/
,p
q
IN
```

the trick here is to try to replace `PATTERN` on `1st` line with itself. `ed` will error out if it can't find the specified pattern so `,p` (print whole file) will only be executed if `1s/PATTERN/&/` is successful.

Or with `sed`:

```
sed -n '1{
/PATTERN/!q
}
p' infile
```

this `q`uits if the first line does not (`!`) match `PATTERN`, otherwise it `p`rints all lines.
Or, as pointed out by *Toby Speight*, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed '1{/PATTERN/!Q}' infile
```

`Q` is the same as `q` but it does not print the pattern space.

Comment: _`d` restarts the command cycle_ That always catches me out!  :-|

Comment: With GNU `sed` the first `sed` command complains `sed: -e expression #1, char 10: extra characters after command` (because of the `p`), but the `ed` and last `sed` suggestions work fine.

Comment: NB : Solutions provided by this answer have the merit, over other answers, that they can be applied on a pipe.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou - you tried turning it into a one-liner without separating the commands with semicolons - this is the proper way to do it `sed -n '1{/PATTERN/!q};p'`

Answer (score 15):

With POSIX tools chest:

```
{ head -n 1 | grep pattern && cat; } <file
```

Comment: { double } <sweet.

Comment: @mikeserv: I intend to use it to prevent new person from confusing, but Stephane edited is clearer.

Answer (score 8):

```
 awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME}; {nextfile}' ./*.txt
```

would print the name of the non-hidden `txt` files in the current directory whose first line matches the extended regular expression `pattern` with [those `awk` inplementations that support `nextfile`](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607).

If instead of printing the file name, you want to print the whole file content, you can do:

```
 awk 'FNR == 1 && ! /pattern/ {nextfile}; {print}' ./*.txt
```

That's efficient in that it runs only one command, but `awk` being not the most efficient command to dump the content of a file, with large files, you could possibly obtain better performances by doing something like:

```
 awk '/pattern/{printf "%s\0", FILENAME}; {nextfile}' ./*.txt |
   xargs -r0 cat
```

That is, only use `awk` to print the list of files that match (0-delimited) and rely on `cat` to dump their content.

Answer (score 6):

If you're writing a shell script, you could so something like

```
for file in ./*; do head -n 1 "$file" | grep -q 'PATTERN' && cat "$file"; done
```

Or, in Perl:

```
perl -Tlne '$f = /PATTERN/ if $. == 1; print if $f; $. = 0 if eof' ./*
```

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: Maybe `close ARGV` is more idiom than assigning to `$.`.

Comment: @terdon Yours looks like code golf, all in one line, no brackets around the variable names and is not encouraging clean structure. And you had a missing dollar sign when I posted, that's just not the way to teach bash. I assume those factors come from the perl background you also seem to have, so you shall be forgiven! ;)

Comment: @guest hi and welcome to the site! I converted your answer to a comment since answers should only be posted if they are answering the actual question. This is not a forum in the classic sense and we only want pure Q&A here. You might want to take a look at the [help] or take the [tour] to understand the site better. That said, my background is actually in biology so yes, my code is far from clean :) However, I don't see how brackets would help here, the quotes already protect the variable. What would break this that brackets would protect from?

Comment: @guest ah, sorry, forgot you can't comment. Feel free to come and explain in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux), I'm sure I might learn something.

Answer (score 5):

Oldschool, just translate your sentence into standard commands:

```
for file in *; do
    if head -n 1 "${file}" | grep -q 'PATTERN'; then
        cat "${file}"
    fi
done
```

For learning bash that is a good start. If you just need a quick solution, try the sed-, awk- or perl-answers. Both nice, but they are own languages you need (and probably want) to learn.

It's a pretty simple example, so if you want to learn more, you could also try the same in ruby, php, js (e.g. in nodejs) or any other language that allows file access. Even C/C++ or Java should be easy to manage with a small task.

Comment: This is basically the same as [mine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232628/22222) except that you use `if/else` instead of `[ ] &&`.