# how to check if the first line of file contain a specific string?

Tags: shell, grep, read

I need to write a shell script that find and print all files in a directory which starts with the string: `#include`.
Now, I know how to check if a string is in the file, by using:

```
for f in `ls`; do
    if grep -q 'MyString' $f; then:
        #DO SOMETHING
    fi
```

but how can I apply this to the first line?
I thought to maybe create a variable of the first line and check if it starts with `#include`, but I'm not sure how to do this. I tried the `read` command but I fail to read into a variable.

I'd like to hear other approaches to this problem; maybe awk?
Anyway, remember, I need to check if the first line starts with `#include`, not if it contains that string.
That's why I found those questions: [How to print file content only if the first line matches a certain pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232608/how-to-print-file-content-only-if-the-first-line-matches-a-certain-pattern)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536018/how-to-print-matched-regex-pattern-using-awk
they are not completely helping.

Comment: Tip: don't use ls in scripts, it invariably leads to problems.

Comment: I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232655/117549 is reasonably close -- just anchor the pattern.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor so I shall use "in *" instead? no problem... but what kind of problem  'ls' can cause?

Comment: It is just that `ls` is hard to parse, it was not designed for the computer to read, but for humans. It is often used when not needed. There are other tools: just that are designed for the job: `*`, `find`, …

Comment: It's a fine line for me on the duplicate, since it's 99% the same idea, with this question requiring the anchor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is easy to check if the first line starts with `#include` in (GNU and AT&T) sed:

```
sed -n '1{/^#include/p};q'   file
```

Or simplified (and POSIX compatible):

```
sed -n '/^#include/p;q'   file
```

That will have an output only if the file contains `#include` in the first line. That only needs to read the first line to make the check, so it will be very fast.

So, a shell loop for all files (with sed) should be like this:

```
for file in *
do
    [ "$(sed -n '/^#include/p;q' "$file")" ] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

**If** there are only files (not directories) in the pwd.

If what you need is to print all lines of the file, a solution similar to the first code posted will work (GNU & AT&T version):

```
sed -n '1{/^#include/!q};p'  file
```

Or, (BSD compatible POSIXfied version):

```
sed -ne '1{/^#include/!q;}' -e p  file
```

Or:

```
sed -n '1{
           /^#include/!q
         }
         p
       '  file
```

Comment: it prints the name of the file/s, not its content... I just replaced the 'printf' with "cat $file" and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @ZENir - so, you've found a question that has answers that show _how to print the whole content, you've even included a link to that question in your post_, you ask about something slightly different and then you complain in the comment above that the solution prints the file name _instead of its content_ ? I mean, really... I have to bookmark this page... What is your actual question ? Do you want the file names or their content ?

Answer (score 6):

```
for file in *; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  IFS= read -r line < "$file" || [ -n "$line" ] || continue
  case $line in
    ("#include"*) printf '%s\n' "$file"
  esac
done
```

To print the content of the file instead of its name, replace the `printf` command with `cat < "$file"`.

If your `awk` supports the `nextfile` extension, and you don't care about the potential side effects of opening non-regular files:

```
awk '/^#include/{print substr(FILENAME, 3)}; {nextfile}' ./*
```

Above, we're [adding a `./` prefix which we're stripping afterwards in `FILENAME` to avoid problems with file names containing `=` characters (or a file called `-`)](/a/490535).

With `zsh`, you can replace `./*` with `./*(-.)` to only pass regular files (or symlinks to regular files like for the `[ -f ... ]` approach above) to `awk`.

Or to print the file contents instead of name:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {found = /^#include/}; found' ./*
```

(that one is portable).

Comment: I tried this script, for some reason it does nothing, I have a file starts with '#include' and still nothing printes, If I press 'Enter' nine times i'm returning to the bash

Comment: @ZENir, in my initial version of the script, I had forgotten the `< "$file"`. Try reloading the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *
do
  [ -f "$file" ] && head -n 1 < "$file" | grep -q '^#include' && cat < "$file"
done
```

Beware of the fact that, with `-q` option enabled, `grep` will exit with a zero status even if an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a perfect example where bash and sed solutions are quite complex, but the task can be much simpler with (GNU) awk:

```
gawk 'FNR==1 && /^#include/{print FILENAME}{nextfile}' *
```

Comment: A similar solution has already been given. Yours has issues with file names that contain `=` characters. Note that a few other `awk` implementations beside GNU `awk` support `nextfile` these days. Here, because you're using `FNR == 1`, it would also work in implementations that don't support `nextfile`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're right, I read your answer too fast and didn't notice your awk examples, sorry about that